# Adjust screen resolution for things like skype or goto meeting

Tags: macos, resolution, skype, screen-sharing

I have an ultrawide monitor and when I need to screen share using GoTo meeting or Skype the text on my screen for viewers is incredibly small due to the resolution of my monitor being so large and them trying view it on a much smaller 13' or 15' laptop. Is there anyway to adjust the resolution of my screen during screen sharing without physically changing my resolution in settings before I share my screen and then having to set it back.

This is on OSX.